# How to create confirmation dialog when error occurs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I would like to implement following functionality: If user write "wrong" PID, alert should show up saying: Do you really save this PID with invalid format? If user say yes, the whole "playerform" (if other fields are correct) will be saved to the database (eventhough that PID would be in incorrect format.)
So how can I achieve this? I would add `@Patern(with right regex) and message` - this message will be displayed to the user because of the template down below, but how can I add this kind of dialog (yes - save the form with invalid PID, no - do not save it).
Spring boot and thymeleaf are used.

Method in the controller

```
@PostMapping("/create")
    public String createPlayer(@Valid @ModelAttribute("playerForm") PlayerForm playerForm,
                               BindingResult bindingResult,
                               Model model,
                               RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        // Check for errors
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            formViewPreparer.prepare(model, new PlayerFormViewPreparer.ParamObj(true, null));

            return "admin/players/create";
        }
        // Prepare object for service layer
        CreatePlayerIn createPlayerIn = CreatePlayerInMapper.fromPlayerForm(playerForm);
        // Call service layer
        playerService.createPlayer(createPlayerIn);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "player.toast.created");

        return "redirect:/admin/players";
    }
```

Player form class

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class PlayerForm {

    @NotBlank
    private String firstName;
    @NotBlank
    private String lastName;
    @NotNull
    private GenericState playerState;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate birthDate;
    private String PID;
    private Long schoolId;
    private Long teamId;
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String zipCode;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String email;
    private String motherPhoneNumber;
    private String motherEmail;
    private String fatherPhoneNumber;
    private String fatherEmail;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate validityOfMedicalExam;
    @NumberFormat(style = NumberFormat.Style.NUMBER)
    @Min(0)
    private Integer annualFee;
    private String annualFeeNote;
    @NumberFormat(style = NumberFormat.Style.NUMBER)
    @Min(0)
    private Integer firstSemiAnnualFee;
    private String firstSemiAnnualFeeNote;
    @NumberFormat(style = NumberFormat.Style.NUMBER)
    @Min(0)
    private Integer secondSemiAnnualFee;
    private String secondSemiAnnualFeeNote;
```

create.html template utilizing thymeleaf

```
<form th:object="${playerForm}"
          th:action="@{/admin/players/create}"
          novalidate
          enctype="multipart/form-data"
          method="post">
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" th:field="*{PID}" class="form-control" th:errorclass="is-invalid"
                                       th:placeholder="#{player.input.PID}"/>
                                <label for="PID" th:text="#{player.input.PID}" class="form-control-placeholder"></label>
                                <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('PID')}" class="invalid-feedback"
                                     th:errors="*{PID}"></div>
                            </div>
```